# how to make a clickable listview

Tags: java, android, eclipse, mobile

Ok. I'm working on a project, I have already created the listview, but I want to click on it and go to another page e.g like when you click a button it goes to another page, exactly like that, this is my code so far:

```
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class listV extends ListActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setListAdapter( new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.listview,Food));

    ListView list = getListView();
    list.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ((TextView)      arg1).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    });

}




static final String[] Food = new String[]{
"Physical Activity" , "Healthy Diet", "Childhood Obesity"

};

}
```

Any help would be appreciated.
I'm just a beginner so please try to explain in detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're 95% of the way there.  In your onItemClick method of the listener, you just have to start the new activity like you normally would.  You can use the 3rd argument of the onItemClick to give you the position of the listview item that was click and use that to differentiate the activity you call OR pass it into a single activity:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View position, int arg2, long arg3) {

        Intent i;
        if( position == 1 ){           
            i = new Intent(listV.this, MyFirstActivity.class);
        } else if (position == 2){           
            i = new Intent(listV.this, MySecondActivity.class);
        } else if (position == 3) {
            i = new Intent(listV.this, MyThirdActivity.class);
        } else {
            return;
        }           
        startActivity(i);

}
```

Comment: okay i have input the code, but now it just gives me an error from the "putExtra" "The method putExtra(String, boolean) in the type Intent is not applicable for the arguments (String, View)"

Comment: Just edit my answer. Don't use startActivityForResult.. just a regular startActivity.  Also, I had the wrong argument labeled as position (the 2nd instead of the 3rd).  Sorry for the typos.  It should be good now.

Comment: OK , thanks so very much for your help but still not getting what i need to do , so i have implemented the code, now the code only lets me open up one page, so i have 3 pages i want to open up , so when i click each of it , it goes to a specific activity , not open up 1 activity when i click the 3 different lines , sorry for confusion tho i suck at this

Comment: No worries.  I was just giving that to you as example and as I said, you could use logic to open each individual activity OR just pass in the position to a single activity.  I was showing you the latter.  I just changed it to show you how to set different intents based on the position selected.  Starting to get it?

Comment: Either am just and idiot, or im just not meant to do programming ,
i think i would just abandon this , and just go with buttons instead, thanks so much for your help tho , really appreciated it a lot, thanks again

Answer (score 1):

I am a fairly new programmer myself and I am attempting to create the same thing.  A ListView where the user is able to click each individual item in the list and each item will start its own activity. Please check out my code based on the help you gave earlier.

```
package com.tylerbmc.test;

import android.app.ListActivity;

import android.content.Intent;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class Main extends ListActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            getResources().getStringArray(R.array.abdominals)));

    ListView list = getListView();
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {


        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {

            Intent i;

            if (position == 1) {
                i = new Intent(Main.this, Second.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
            else if (position == 2) {
                i = new Intent(Main.this, Third.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }




        }
    }); 

}
```

}